# Picamera slow capture

Tags: pi-3, raspicam

I am using raspberry pi camera on CSI2 interface on Pi3. I have performance problems. I simplified the code to only capture module and it takes around 0.5 sec.  What is the solution?

```
import time
import picamera
import numpy

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 24
    camera.raw_format='rgb'
    time.sleep(2)
    output = numpy.empty((480, 640, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    while 1:
            a=time.time()
            camera.capture(output, 'raw')
            b=time.time()
            print(b-a)
```

Comment: Don't you need a start_preview before the sleep(2)?  A warmup?

Comment: Captures from the still port implicitly switch the camera's mode to (and then from) one of the two image modes supported (of the 7 modes implemented, all support video capture but only two are used for still images). See [rapid capture and processing](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#rapid-capture-and-processing) for various hints on speeding up captures.